# php - After validation why my form data get cleared

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing PHP validations for my html values. However when PHP validation
fails and I return back to the page, the form data is cleared. Is there anyway to do save and reload the form data in php

## validation code in php

```
<?php
    $firstname=$lastname=$contactno="";
    $firstnameErr=$lastnameErr=$contactnoErr="";
    
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']== "POST") {
       $valid = true;
         
    /*FirstName Validation starts here*/     
     if(empty($_POST["fname"]))
    {
        $firstnameErr="*firstname is Required";
            $valid=false;
    }
    else
    {
    $firstname=test_input($_POST["fname"]);
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$firstname))
           {
           $firstnameErr = "&nbsp;&nbsp;Only letters and white space allowed"; 
           $valid=false;
           }    
    } 
    /*FirstName Validation Ends here*/   
       
       /*lastName Validation starts here*/   
       if(empty($_POST["lname"]))
       {
           $lastnameErr="*lastname is required";
           $valid=false;
       }
       else
       {
           $lastname=test_input($_POST["lname"]);
           if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$lastname))
           {
               $lastnameErr = "&nbsp;&nbsp;Only letters and white space allowed";
               $valid=false;
           }
       }
       /*LastName Validation Ends here*/     
        
    /*Contact No Validation starts here*/    
       if(empty($_POST["contact"]))
       {
           $contactnoErr="*Contact No. is required";
           $valid=false;
        }
        else
        {
            $contactno=test_input($_POST["contact"]);
             if(!preg_match("/^(\d[\s-]?)?[\(\[\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\)\]\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$/i",$contactno)) 
           {
            $contactnoErr="*Enter a valid contact no";
            $valid=false;
           }    
        }
       /*Contact No Validation Ends here*/
         
     //if valid then redirect
      if($valid){
          include 'database.php';
          echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=success.php">';    
        exit;
      }  
    }
    
    function test_input($data)
    {
         $data = trim($data);
         $data = stripslashes($data);
         $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
         return $data;
    }
    
    ?>
```

## form

```
<form method="post" action="<?php htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
        <label>Firstname<span class="error">*</span>:</label>
        <input type="text" name="fname"/>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $firstnameErr?></span><br />
        <br />
        <label>lastname<span class="error">*</span>:</label>
        <input type="text" name="lname"/>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $lastnameErr?></span><br />
        <br />
        <label>contactno<span class="error">*</span>:</label>
        <input type="text" name="contact"/>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $contactnoErr?></span>
        <br />
    <input style="margin:20px 20px 20px 250px;" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: `<input type="text" name="lname"/>` - Your input fields are always empty on page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit your form, you basically reload your page from scratch. And since you don't provide values for it - it is empty. You need to do something like this in your form.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <label>Firstname<span class="error">*</span>:</label>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($_POST['fname']); ?>" name="fname"/>
    <span class="error"><?php echo $firstnameErr?></span><br />
    <br />
    <label>lastname<span class="error">*</span>:</label>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($_POST['lname']); ?>" name="lname"/>
    <span class="error"><?php echo $lastnameErr?></span><br />
    <br />
    <label>contactno<span class="error">*</span>:</label>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($_POST['contact']); ?>" name="contact"/>
    <span class="error"><?php echo $contactnoErr?></span>
    <br />
    <input style="margin:20px 20px 20px 250px;" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Don't add unfiltered user-input to the output!

Comment: It's an example, not the code i would actually use, but i got your point and made an edit, thanks. Upvote too for you.

Comment: @АндрейПочекуев thank u so much: This value attribute is for without validation. its working.

Answer (score 1):

You are loading a new form (even if it is identical to the last one loaded) and you don't have `value` attributes for any of your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Add the value-element to your input tags:

`<input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $firstname ?>" />`

And make sure, that all values have a preset.

Comment: thank u seb ur answer is correct but small mistake u have done

Comment: <input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $firstname ?>" />

Comment: seb u forgot to put $ sign

Comment: how to put value attribute in select tag:                <select name="loca" >
      <option label="Select"></option>
      <option>Andaman and Nicobar Islands</option><option>Andhra Pradesh</option></select><span class="error"><?php echo $locationErr?></span>

Answer (score 0):

Validate it from memory, not from fields. Save it either to an object or simply in some variables which you will use. If the values are invalid just return the same page and fill it out from the vars/object again to allow the user to continue.

Also you might want to add a client-side validation before this, so the most trivial non-valid data is fixed without doing a request onto your server.